# leapmotion creating a valid device -> adding to valid controller

Tags: c++, leap-motion

have been checking through the examples and api, but i cant seem to find how to initialize the device and adding it to a controller.

```
Controller controller; //creates an invalid controller
Device device; //creates an invalid device
```

there seems to be no knowledge to be found past that.
if these actually are supposed to make valid devices on the spot: then there might be a device find error, however i already have leapd and leapcontrolpanel started up and working.

Answer (score 0):

You don't create Device objects yourself. The Device class describes connected devices. Get a Device object from the Controller object after the controller has "connected". (Currently only one Leap Motion device can be recognized.)